# How to get data in Anthos Metrics for Kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, google-kubernetes-engine

We have one project and there are two clusters inside. We would like to monitor and set alert policies for plenty of parameters like kube_pod_status_phase, kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total, etc. We are able to see all these parameters in Metric Explorer (with prefix kubernetes.io/anthos/..) but it doesn't show any data. Can anyone please guide us if any other configurations are missing to use Anthos Metrics? Or if anyone can provide a guide or steps to use Anthos Metrics?

Note: We have Istio configured in both clusters and we are using Workload Identity feature as well.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you configure `Stackdriver` or `Prometheus` as per: https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/how-to/monitoring ? What did you try?

Comment: No we haven't tried this yet. We have implemented kube-state metrics in one of the test clusters which worked fine but in this pricing list (https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#monitoring-costs) it looks Anthos Metrics are non-chargeable hence we would like to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to use this metrics.

Anthos, Anthos GKE and GKE **are 3 different** google products.

[GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine):

> is an enterprise-grade platform for containerized applications, including stateful and stateless, AI and ML, Linux and Windows, complex and simple web apps, API, and backend services. Leverage industry-first features like four-way auto-scaling and no-stress management. Optimize GPU and TPU provisioning, use integrated developer tools, and get multi-cluster support from SREs.

[Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos)

> is an open hybrid and multi-cloud application platform that enables you to modernize your existing applications, build new ones, and run them anywhere in a secure manner. Built on open source technologies pioneered by Google—including Kubernetes, Istio, and Knative—Anthos enables consistency between on-premises and cloud environments and helps accelerate application development.

[Anthos GKE](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke)

> is part of Anthos, lets you take advantage of Kubernetes and cloud technology in your data center and in the cloud. You get Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) experience with quick, managed, and simple installs as well as upgrades validated by Google. And Google Cloud Console gives you a single pane of glass view for managing your clusters across on-premises and cloud environments.

If you will check information about `Anthos GKE` pricing you can read that:

> Anthos is available as a monthly, term-based subscription service. Anthos subscription is required to use Anthos GKE. For pricing please contact sales.

So to get `Anthos metrics`, you would need to use `Anthos GKE`, which requires `Anthos subscription`. It can produce more costs, for details you would probably need to contact sales.

For monitoring purposes you should check possibilities described [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine#skm-howto) and choose what would fit you best.

However, the most used ways are to use [Prometheus on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus) and [Stackdriver](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-monitoring-tutorial).

In addition, in the web you can find many HowTo regarding Monitoring on GKE like [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gke-monitoring-84170ea44833).